# image looks overexposed (nearly all white) when using np.zeros with OpenCV imshow

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am writing a code in openCV python for copying an image for practice purpose only, though `np.copy()` command is already available. Code is as below:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('Photos/image_1.jpg')
r, c, d = img.shape
img_copy = np.zeros((r, c, d))
for i in range(r):
    for j in range(c):
        for k in range(d):
            img_copy[i, j, k] = img[i, j, k]

cv.imshow('original image', img)
cv.imshow('copied image', img_copy)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

The **img_copy** is not shown instead black image is shown. If I use `img_copy = np.ones(rows, cols, 3)`, and apply same `for` loop, still then a white image is shown, original image is not shown. Can any one explain why this occures? Original and copied images are shown below.

[image][image]

Comment: You aren't specifying a `dtype` for the new image array, so it's probably defaulting to floats rather than integers.

Comment: thanks, @jasonharper, I specified `dtype=numpy.uint8`, and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

This issue was caused by incompatible data types.
To determine the data type of the image, use

```py
img = cv.imread('Photos/image_1.jpg')
print(img.dtype)
```

In my testing case, the output data type was `uint8`

Changing

```py
img_copy = np.zeros((r, c, d))
```

to

```py
img_copy = np.zeros((r, c, d), dtype=np.uint8)
```

will fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV's `imshow()` is sensitive to the **element type** of the array you pass it.

- When the element type is `np.uint8`, the values must be in the range of `0` to `255`.
- When the element type is `np.float32` or `np.float64`, the values must be in the range of `0.0` to `1.0`.

You have two options:

- Either **scale** your values: `img_copy / 255`
- Or clip and **convert** your values: `np.clip(img_copy, 0, 255).astype(np.uint8)`